# How can I quickly select each subdirectory with keystroke

Tags: bash, shell

When I hit `ls` and it shows a list of directories. How can I use keyboard to cyclic through those directories to copy the name of each directory and decide what to do with them?

For example, if I have three directories: `a/`, `b/`, and `c/`. Instead of using mouse to highlight the name of directory to copy the name and paste it into shell prompt to `cd` into, can I use some keystroke to walk through the `a/`, `b/`, and `c/` and highlight them so that I can copy without having my hand using mouse?

Thanks!

Comment: Not that I know of. A GUI file manager (or something like `dired` in emacs) would be what I would use in such cases.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for shell completion as provided by the `complist` module  on the `zsh` sell or that of  the `fish` shell.

Comment: Thanks I can check this out.

Comment: **bash** has also a [programmable completion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Programmable-Completion) using the `<TAB>` key. E.g. for `cd` it completes until the common prefix of the current directory subdirectories, then you need to disambiguate by adding another character or hitting `<TAB>` again to list the possible completions.